# How to add scroll arrow buttons to left and right scroll wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to replace a scrollbar that moves left and right and put some type of arrows on the left and right side that allow you to scroll or move through the left and right scrollbar to make it easier.

See here for a picture of the website to understand what I mean:

http://s3.postimg.org/7dlnenzbl/nonavigation.png

Here is the link to the site:

http://aster.themevillage.net/

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean like this? 
http://favbulous.com/wp-content/uploads/uploaded/design.jpg

Comment: @JoshHarrison yes like that.  The arrows.

Comment: if you google 'carousel' you will find a bunch of libraries to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var buttonR = document.getElementById('buttonR');
  var buttonL = document.getElementById('buttonL');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  buttonR.onclick = function () {
    container.scrollLeft += (window.innerWidth / 2);
  };

  buttonL.onclick = function () {
    container.scrollLeft -= (window.innerWidth / 2);
  };
}, false);
```

```css
#container{
  width: 1280px /*screen width*/;
  overflow:scroll;
}
#content{
  width: 700vw /*width of your page content*/;
}
  
#buttonR, #buttonL {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 75px;
  background: grey;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#buttonR{
  right: 100px;
}

#buttonL{
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  <div id="buttonR">></div>
  <div id="buttonL"><</div>
</div>
```